# Capturing List response for a Retrofit Call with Json body

Tags: android, json, arraylist, retrofit, retrofit2

All.

I am trying to use Retrofit to send raw json as a body in a POST Request to the server.

```
@POST("api/apps")
Call<List<GetApps>> getApp(@Body GetApps body);
```

I have built the model using jsontopojo for the responses that are coming back.

Inside my call, I have put the constructors and the getters and setters and also toString().

This is my retrofit call.

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASEURL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

        APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiService.getApp();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetApps>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GetApps>> call, Response<List<GetApps>> response) {
                List<GetApps> GetApps2 = response.body();


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GetApps>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
```

I am getting an error on this line :

```
Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiService.getApp();
```

It says getApp(getApps) cannot be applied to (); Not sure what should go into the ();

Comment: You didn't pass the parameter jsonObject in your getApp method

Comment: Please post the response also

Comment: @SubinBabu It is showing error in the Android studio, so I cannot even send a request or even run the app.

Comment: @AbhayBohra please request your API use postman and get the response and update here.

Comment: The Postman request which I am sending has correct json body and it is giving me correct response.  the trouble that I am facing is about formulating the request inside the Activity of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass `GetApps` object as parameter:

```
GetApps getApps = new GetApps();
//set all your data on getApps
//getApps.setYourData(yourData);
Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiService.getApp(getApps);
```

Comment: What data should I set? The one that I am posting as part of the body of the  Request or the list of json objects that would come back as the response.

Comment: So you're not passing a request body? `GetApps` is for handling the response body of the API?

Comment: What is getApps for? Is it for the request body or the response body?  Because if I do as you are saying, it is expecting me to place the response body attributes inside.

Comment: You set @Body GetApps as request body because it is on the parameter. Plus, you also use the same object as response body on `Call<List<GetApps>> getApp`. Im clarifying what actually are you trying to do. Ive solved your error as what youve indicated.

Comment: `GetApps getApps = new GetApps(name, place, time);
Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiService.getApp(getApps);`  I had this line already, but commented out as looks like it is expecting my response body parameters.   That's what is confusing me.

Comment: Finally solved it. I got my getApps in the call and the getApps in the POJO model mixed up. So when I placed my POJO model's getApps, it was expecting those attributes.   Thank you @tenten-ponce

Comment: Thats it, youre confused with the request and the response of retrofit. Well, youve made it. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You make request

```
@POST("api/apps")
Call<List<GetApps>> getApp(@Body GetApps body);
```

which will accept body that will append to URL.

just add body in `getApp(@Body GetApps body);` // accept JSON string as a parameter.

Happy coding!!

Comment: `Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiService.getApp(@Body GetApps body);` 
  when I do this I get 2 errors.  1. Annotations are not allowed here. 2. Cannot resolve symbol Body.   But that is what exactly I placed when I was creating the request inside the interface.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of Post just add `@FormEncodedUrl` and pass a GetApp model as body ... 
      `Call<List<GetApps>> call = apiservice.getApp(getAppOne);`

Comment: I dont think I can add the `@FormEncodedUrl`, because this is a Raw JSON Body post to the URL. If I use the `@FormEncodedUrl` then my request would not work, as, at the the server side, I am parsing my json and extracting information inside the json body.