# Json parsing using Gson and Retrofit (Custom Deserializer)

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

I need to build list of places (from `response` array create instance of `place` and finally receive list of places (`place` in json))?

How to parse it using Gson and Retrofit with custom deserializer?

I have following strucutre:

```
{
"success": true,
"error": null,
"response": [
   {
      "loc": {
          "lat": 51.50853,
          "long": -0.12574
      },
      "place": {
           "name": "London",
           "state": "",
           "stateFull": "",
           "country": "GB",
           "countryFull": "United Kingdom",
           "region": "",
           "regionFull": "",
           "continent": "eu",
           "continentFull": "Europe"
       },
       "profile": {
           "elevM": 21,
           "elevFT": 69,
           "pop": 7556900,
           "tz": "Europe/London",
           "tzname": "BST",
           "tzoffset": 3600,
           "isDST": true,
           "wxzone": null,
           "firezone": null,
           "fips": null,
           "countyid": null
        }
      },
       .............
       .............
    ]
}
```

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ use this site to create model class/pojo and to parse using retrofit try  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887422/8089770  https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: First attempt some code and if any issue then ask here with code

Comment: I want to parse it without inner classes, I need custom deserializer

Comment: If you don't want inner classes then move them to upper level, (F6 in Android Studio.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android Studio plugin [RoboPOJOGenerator](https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator). It is very easy to make model classes from data.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056031/6891563) tells how to handle List response in retrofit.

[image: img]

**Update**

I don't think it is good idea to make custom deserializer just to parse a list. When you can filter or map list after getting response. It will take upto 3-4 lines of code.

If you don't want many classes. then you can safely delete `Profile.java` and `Loc.java` in your case, `Gson` will parse only data that you have declared in your pojo.

**Make generic response class**

You can make single class for handling all response by using [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). See example.

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private String error;
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private boolean success;
    @SerializedName("response")
    @Expose
    private T response;

    // make getter setters
}
```

Now in ApiService you can define `response` type. Like this

```
@GET("api/users/login")
Call<ApiResponse<ModelUser>> getUser();

@GET("api/users/login")
Call<ApiResponse<ModelCity>> getCity();
```

Thus you don't have to create 3 classes every time. This generic class will do work for all response.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I want to avoid a lot of classes, I just want one class Place. And after response return list of Place instances. I think for this I need make custom Gson deserializer, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: You want only `place` from this response.

Comment: In your case, you generate all classes from JSON, but I need to have only needed class, without others which I don't use

Comment: Yes, I want only Place class ("place" in JSON), and after response return list of places, because json contains JsonArray where I have object "place", look my JSON above

Comment: Yep, it's better. But as I underastand in this case I will have: `ApiResponse.class` (root of JSON), `Response.class` (`response` in JSON) and finally `Place.class` (`place` in JSON) which I need. But can I leave only `Place.class`,  maybe I'm wrongm but I read that I need to create custom `Deserializer.class` for it where I can achieve my goal

Comment: Or maybe my idea its a bad practise (leaving only needed class `Place.class`), and best approach is your updated answer?

Comment: I posted code for your understanding. This is best approach you should follow.

Comment: Seems like, I understand you! But, plz can u explain in some words, that's the purpose of `@Expose` in that case. Sorry, I'm newer in Retrofit

Comment: When we use proguard for release apk, then some times it cause error, so Expose is used.